# Arcgis for developers - need aerial tile layer with street names

Tags: silverlight, maps, arcgis, esri

I'm using silverlight maps control from ESRI. Currently showing 2 layers (allowing users to switch) between

```
if (this.RoadRadioButton.IsChecked.HasValue && this.RoadRadioButton.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                arcgisLayer.Url = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer";
            }
            else if (this.AerialRadioButton.IsChecked.HasValue && this.AerialRadioButton.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                arcgisLayer.Url = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer";
            }
```

My users would like to have
1. On street view - highway exit numbers
2. On imagery - street names, similar how Bing does it.

Is it possible, is there way to merge layers or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse the services directory for more layer types here: http://services.arcgisonline.com/

Especially look at the service in the References folder:
http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Reference

You can use these as overlays on top of other layers.

On a side-note, don't *ever* change the URL of a running layer - You can get into a LOT of trouble doing that. Instead use two layers, and flip the visibility. That will also make the combo of multiple layers easier. Just put the aerial and the reference layer in a group layer and toggle the group layer. Even better you can bind the Visible parameter of your layer straight to your radio button so you don't need any code behind. Ie

```
  <GroupLayer Visible="{Binding IsChecked.Value, ElementName=AerialRadioButton}">
       <!-- add your composite set of layers here -->
  </GroupLayer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Those transparent overlays is exactly what I needed. I got sample of changing URL straight from ESRI silverlight samples (their radio button switching sample does it)